Neo4j full text search - common node
I need to find one common node for FTS results.

I have created fts index on TRANSLATION node type on "text" property. Now I have keywords “home” and “house” and want to search for BOX node that have something in common with those words.
So query should return node BOX with id “b1” because it has DETAILs that have TRANSLATION that contains “home” and “house”.
BOX node with id "b2" should not be returned because it contains only "house" keyword but not "home".
How to achieve that? Is it possible with fts? Maybe I have to index it another way?
One thing that comes to mind is to call FTS two (or x) times for every keyword and then get nodes that appeared in both (x) results.

The Full Text Index seems like a helpful solution for you. It searches the property you have indexed using the following syntax:
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes

I would also recommend digging into the apoc.text libraries.
apoc.text.fuzzyMatch seems like a really solid fit for this use case.
Something along the lines of:
MATCH (n:Translation)
WITH apoc.text.fuzzyMatch(toLower(n.details), toLower(${searchTerm})) AS fuzzyMatch, n
WHERE fuzzyMatch = true
RETURN n LIMIT 10

Also, since this is has translation applications, apoc.text.phonetic might be good too.
Docs:
apoc.text.fuzzyMatch
apoc.text.phonetic
